# ¿Cómo validar en un radio button si es mayor de edad o no al pulsarlo en javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Hola estoy haciendo una aplicación sencilla, donde el radio button decide si la persona es mayor de edad o no, y si este es mayor de edad que aparezca un input para introducir su nombre, pero solo he sido capaz de sacar un alert en cada uno de los checked, aquí el ejemplo :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
function comprobar() {
        if(document.getElementById('si').checked){
            
            alert('Has seleccionado SI');
    
        }
        if(document.getElementById('no').checked){
            alert('Has seleccionado NO');
        }
    }
    
    document.getElementById('prefijo').addEventListener('input',validarPrefijo);
        
        var pulsado = false;
        var opciones = document.formulario.edad;
    
        function validarPrefijo() {
            var prefijo = document.getElementById('prefijo').value,
            resultado = document.getElementById('resPrefijo');
    
            expReg = /^968[-]\d{2}[-]\d{2}[-]\d{2}$/;
            if(expReg.test(prefijo)){
                resultado.innerText = "Coincide con 968-xx-xx-xx";
            }else{
                resultado.innerText = "El prefijo no coincide con 968"; 
            }
        }
```

```html
 <form method="POST" name="formulario">
        <fieldset>
        <label for="male">Usuario : </label><br>
        <input type="text" id="prefijo" placeholder="Teléfono 968">
        <fieldset>
        <legend>¿Eres mayor de edad?</legend>
            <input type="radio" name="edad" id="si" value="si"/>   
            <label for="edad">Si</label>
            <input type="radio" name="edad" id="no" value="no"/>   
            <label for="edad">No</label>  
        </fieldset>
        <div id="introduce_tu_nombre"></div>
        <div id="resPrefijo"></div>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Validar" onclick="comprobar()">
    </form>
```

Comment: Puedes cambiar la imagen de tu html por el código, asi podemos copiarlo

Comment: listo es que no me dejaba enviarla con tantas lineas de código un saludo !

Comment: @NicolasOñate gracias por reescribir la pregunta, haber si alguien puede echarme un cable un saludo !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lo que hice fue declarar el campo nombre y ocultarlo y dependiendo del resultado del radio button muestra u oculta el campo nombre, espero te ayude.

Edite un poco el código para que reaccione al click sobre uno de los Radio Button

```js
function validaNombre(rdButton) {
  var x = document.getElementById('campoNombre');
  if (rdButton.value == 'si') {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
  if (rdButton.value == 'no') {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

document.getElementById('prefijo').addEventListener('input', validarPrefijo);

var pulsado = false;
var opciones = document.formulario.edad;
var areaNombre = document.getElementById('campoNombre');

areaNombre.style.display = "none";

function validarPrefijo() {
  var prefijo = document.getElementById('prefijo').value,
    resultado = document.getElementById('resPrefijo');

  expReg = /^968[-]\d{2}[-]\d{2}[-]\d{2}$/;
  if (expReg.test(prefijo)) {
    resultado.innerText = "Coincide con 968-xx-xx-xx";
  } else {
    resultado.innerText = "El prefijo no coincide con 968";
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" name="formulario">
  <fieldset>
    <label for="male">Usuario : </label><br>
    <input type="text" id="prefijo" placeholder="Teléfono 968">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>¿Eres mayor de edad?</legend>
      <input type="radio" name="edad" id="si" value="si" onclick="validaNombre(this);" />
      <label for="edad">Si</label>
      <input type="radio" name="edad" id="no" value="no" onclick="validaNombre(this);" />
      <label for="edad">No</label>
    </fieldset>
    <div id="introduce_tu_nombre"></div>
    <div id="resPrefijo"></div>
    <br>
    <div id="campoNombre">
      <label>Nombre : </label><br>
      <input type="text" id="txtNombre" placeholder="Agregue Nombre">
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Validar" onclick="comprobar()">
</form>
```

Comment: Gracias @JoséVenegas ahora el problema está en que si yo ejecuto el formulario desaparece, y lo que tiene que hacer es estar visible, creo que no lo ejecuta bien de ltodo

Comment: es necesario que este en JavaScript puro o puedes utilizar alguna librería como Jquery?

Comment: es puro sin librerías

Comment: entiendo, entonces con el ejemplo actual debería bastar, me comentas si hay algún problema ;)

Comment: Esta correcto muchas gracias @José Venegas ! un saludo